# How to find the id of an object within an array having only one identified attribute of the "child" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, reduce

I would like help to develop a function using the most optimized approach in Javascript to find the id of the "parent" object having only a code of an "child" object (inside dataArray).

Example:
getIdParent("240#code") -> return "1"

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        dataArray:[
            {
                id: 182,
                code: "182#code",
                name: "Product1"
            },
            {
                id: 183,
                code: "183#code",
                name: "Product2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        dataArray:[
            {
                id: 240,
                code: "240#code",
                name: "Product2"
            },
            {
                id: 341,
                code: "341#code",
                name: "Product2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have a lot of options here.

The only real optimisation I can think of is based on how often you expect to call this function.

If it's only once, you just need to iterate the array, searching for values and return as early as possible to prevent unnecessary iterations.

```js
function getIdParent(childCode) {
  return arr.find(parent =>
    parent.dataArray.some(({ code }) => code === childCode))?.id
}
```

If multiple times, you should build up an indexed map of child `code` to parent object and then reference that

```js
const arr = [{"id":0,"dataArray":[{"id":182,"code":"182#code","name":"Product1"},{"id":183,"code":"183#code","name":"Product2"}]},{"id":1,"dataArray":[{"id":240,"code":"240#code","name":"Product2"},{"id":341,"code":"341#code","name":"Product2"}]}]

const codeMap = arr.reduceRight((map, parent) => {
  parent.dataArray.forEach(({ code }) => {
    map.set(code, parent)
  })
  return map
}, new Map())

function getIdParent(code) {
  return codeMap.get(code)?.id
}

let search = ["240#code", "182#code", "NotFound"]
search.forEach(code => {
  console.log("Parent ID for", code, "=", getIdParent(code))
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phil! In my case it was only possible to use the first function that you addressed.
```arr.find(parent => parent.dataArray.some(({ code }) => code === childCode))?.id```

Comment: That's odd. As you can see from my answer, the second method also works just fine